# Implementing FullDeps in Substrate rpc.rs using channels instead of Arcs

Tags: rpc, substrate-node, moonbeam, custom-rpc, service

This is a standard implementation of `FullDeps` in the `rpc.rs`:

```
// Full client dependencies.
pub struct FullDeps<C, P, SC, B> {
    /// The client instance to use.
    pub client: Arc<C>,
    /// Transaction pool instance.
    pub pool: Arc<P>,
    /// The SelectChain Strategy
    pub select_chain: SC,
    /// Whether to deny unsafe calls
    pub deny_unsafe: DenyUnsafe,
    /// BABE specific dependencies.
    pub babe: BabeDeps,
    /// GRANDPA specific dependencies.
    pub grandpa: GrandpaDeps<B>,
}
```

I'm working on implementing `FullDeps` in the `rpc.rs` file for a Substrate-based project. The standard implementation uses `Arc` for various dependencies like `client`, `pool`, etc. However, I'm interested in using channels instead of `Arcs` to manage these dependencies in `create_full` and `service.rs`.

I've noticed other projects like [`moonbeam`](https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/master/node/service/src/rpc.rs#L122) and [`AlephZero`](https://github.com/aleph-zero-foundation/aleph-node/blob/main/bin/node/src/rpc.rs#L30) employing channels for their custom objects, but these objects differ from the standard dependencies like `client` and `pool`. The challenge I'm facing is that when using channels, the value is consumed upon calling `recv`, subsequently blocking the thread until a new value is received.

Could anyone provide suggestions or insights on how to implement `FullDeps` using channels while ensuring the ownership of these objects for Substrate methods?

Thank you for your help!